# Minimum CI slave requirements to build MVC TFS solution

Tags: visual-studio, build, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

What are the minimum requirements for pulling and building a TFS hosted Visual Studio 2012 MVC solution on a clean Windows 2012 Server VM?

I'm setting up a continuous integration slave and I want to install as few tools as possible to get set of projects out of Team Foundation Server source control and building.

My working assumption is that I'll need [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656) to get the files from the TFS server, and [Visual Studio Express 2012 (Web)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web) to actually build the solution.

The CI slave will NOT use Team Foundation Build, rather it will be part of a Jenkins grid. I know they have a plugin for TFS, but I don't know if it can be used in lieu of Team Explorer.

Running of unit tests will follow but the framework to be used has not be decided yet.

The solution has existing NuGet package dependencies and those are not checked in.

Comment: sounds more like a superuser than a programming question

Comment: FYI - generally jenkins plugins just ask for the path to the exe (in this case tf.exe) so I suspect you need Team Explorer if you WANT to use the Jenkins plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661)
- [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)